# sql combine 2 rows into one

Tags: sql, self-join

I have the following dataset:

[image]

I am trying to convert the table on the left into the table on the right. I have several duplicates of orders with the same name but different products sold. I would like to combine the rows so it shows just one orderID. I've tried joining the table to itself based on order but I must be doing something wrong. Do you guys have any suggestions? this is probably super easy but I am not proficient with SQL yet. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add - Group by order,name,product,product2,product3

Comment: The table on the left is a pretty messy table

Comment: If the products for the same order are always in different columns you might select `max(Product1), max(Product2), max(Product3)` and `group by order, name`. I assume that the name for one order is always the same, so the table structure is not really optimal.

Comment: the one on the right is still not well normalized.  you might have an easier time if you get that target table right before you convert things.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is at most one value in each column, you can use `group by`:

```
select order, name, max(product1) as product1, max(product2) as product2,
       max(product3) as product3
from lefttable
group by order, name;
```

That said, I suspect that the table on the left is the result of a query on the data.  You probably simply need the right aggregation for that query.

Also, if you have more than one value in any column for an order, you can still do this, but the query is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Thanks for extending my comment. You might correct `produt3` to `product3`.

Comment: Thank you guys. I was making it too complicated by joining to itself. this is a lot easier.